# Error: Error: TypeError: _this3.props.onError is not a function - Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

While testing Paypal checkout.js REST API client side integration code (on sandbox) - https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client, I received following error -

[image]

[image]

And this behaviour is random. Sometimes it executes and sometimes it fails. Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Add an onError method to your checkout.js button implementation, as seen [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-the-checkout-flow/#handle-checkout-flow-errors).

As for the "Sometimes it executes, sometimes it doesn't", that's PayPal Sandbox for you.